# Iterating Array of Maps in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Lets say I have Array of Maps :

```
   val m1 = Map("key" -> Array("aa","bb"), "v1" -> 1 , "v2" -> 3)
   val m2 = Map("key" -> Array("cc","bb"), "v1" -> 2 , "v2" -> 4)
   val colection = Array(m1,m2)
```

I'd like to create a new collection `val colection2` if value of `v2`  from `collection` is less then 4.  Result is a new collection that contains `m1` only .

I tried `foreach` and `filter` , but I can't get accsess to the value of `v2` 
for example : `val collection2 = collection.filter{case (key,v1,v2) => (v2 < 4) }`

Comment: What should the result look like? How does `collection` differ from `collection2`, I don't get it from your post?

Comment: You'd better get started then! SO isn't a site where you post requirements and hope for some free code (although judging by the amount of reputation you have you should know that), so please add to the question with details about what you have tried and what your specific problem is.

Comment: check if map contains key `v2` and then check if value mapped to `v2` satisfies your condition

Comment: I'm not looking for free code !!!! I'd like to get help from community to understand how to get access to values in particular Map , due the fact I'm new to scala. Thanks a lot .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My answer after some work on issue:

```
val collection2 = for ( m <- collection if m("v2").asInstanceOf[Int] < 4) yield m
```